# Kotlin Date Error "Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected"

Tags: date, kotlin, types, mismatch

```
lateinit var endTime:String
lateinit var enDate:Date

val formatter= SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss")

endTime=tarihBul()+", 00:00:00"

**enDate=formatter.parse(endTime)  -->213**
miliseconds=enDate.time


   private fun tarihBul():String {

        val tarihFormat= SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")
        val tarih= Date()
        val simdiTarih=tarihFormat.format(tarih)


        return simdiTarih.toString()
```

> w: F:\Dersler\Kotlin_uygulamalar\Namazvakitleri\app\src\main\java\com\erdemselvi\namazvakitleri\widget\VakitlerWidget.kt: (213, 16): Type mismatch: inferred type is Date? but Date was expected

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat.parse` is a java function, which can return a nullable Date `Date?` . As `enDate` is defined as `Date` and you are trying to assign to nullable Date, kotlin tries to avoid it and throws an error.

You can either use the **UNSAFE** `!!` operator

```
 enDate=formatter.parse(endTime)!!
```

or handle null case explicitly

```
 enDate=formatter.parse(endTime)?.let{ YOUR LOGIC TO THROW ERROR OR DEFAULT VALUE}
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that the reason `parse()` has a nullable type is because it returns null if the string is not a valid date.  So that's the case you need to consider how to handle.  (There are other ways it could be handled, of course.  But the compiler forces you to handle it somehow.)

Comment: teşekkürler.
!! ile sorun çözüldü.